# Can I mate black in 4 moves in this game

Tags: checkmate

Can I mate black in 4 moves in this game[image]

Comment: Where is this position from ? (After a rapid and possibly flawed calculation, my best guess would be : "no")

Comment: This is from a chess quiz app magic moves. I am stuck on expert quizz#132

Answer (score 2):

This is your third time requesting this type of answer.  I suggest that you either learn to play better or input the position into a computer.

```
[FEN "2r2k2/p4p1p/3pbQnN/3q2Pp/8/2B5/PP5P/K3R3 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qg7+ Ke8 2. Qxf7+ Kd8 3. Bf6+ Ne7 4. Qxe7#
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe yes.

```
[FEN "2r2k2/p4p1p/3pbQnN/3q2Pp/8/2B4P/PP6/K3R3 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qg7+ Ke7 {Ke8 plays out the same}
2. Qxf7+ {the Bishop is pinned} Kd8
3. Bf6+ Ne7
4. Qxe7#
```

Comment: Pardon me for bothering you brothers. I asked when I was stuck. This is the way I was learning better. Anyways I am not gonna bother you anymore. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Rafiq Perhaps you should take the tour, https://chess.stackexchange.com/tour, to understand how this site works.